# вирусы в библиотеках pyhton3?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, вирусы

В общем я написал программу на python+qt, и чтобы выложить на один сайт проверил через ВирусТотал. Использовал библиотеки pyqt, vk_api, requests. Собирал с помощью pyinstaller. Для программы нужна была авторизация в вк, если это важно. Вот отчет на ВТ: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/dfeb84d756adb573199e0576a5485f9e70dbc2f9958318d5c941ce64913f49fb/detection
Может дело в какой-то из библиотек, или в самих антивирусах, знает кто? Буду благодарен, если обьясните почему так. Там на вт загружен архив, но если закидываю только exe то же самое.
Кстати, поискал на зарубержом Stack'e и вот статья, у чела похожая проблема
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777106/program-made-with-pyinstaller-now-seen-as-a-trojan-horse-by-avg

Comment: почему бы не прочекать библиотеки по отдельности? requests и pyqt, если ставили через pip, можно пропустить

Comment: скажу так, все ставил через pip

Comment: соберите hello word черех pyinstaller и проверьте, и можно проверить еще vk_api, если первое не даст результатов

Comment: хорошо, спасибо за совет)

Comment: ахахах ору, собрал helloworld через pyinstaller, вот вт:

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/d335760a46ac46f0003d15588896dd4b9dbccefcfc069b5165349c82d61bc8f8/detection

Comment: а ведь ставил я его через pip

Comment: кстати я файл .py c импортом vk_api закинул на вт, все норм

Comment: Ложное срабатывание.

Comment: похоже на то, так как более авторитетные антивири не реагируют

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Короче, pyinstaller вызывает предупреждения о вирусах на ВТ при загрузке  exe, хотя ставил pip-ом.
Вот в VT:https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/d335760a46ac46f0003d15588896dd4b9dbccefcfc069b5165349c82d61bc8f8/detection
vk_api вроде безопасен

Comment: а ведь я про pyinstaller с хабра узнал

Comment: теперь благодаря тебе мы знаем, что там вирусня

Comment: ))) ну да, при том не заметил ничего такого с компом

Comment: хотя... тихий вирус самый плохой

Comment: если кому помог, очень рад)

Comment: Хмммм так вот почему в моём парсере 6 угроз

Comment: Ох уж этот pyinstaller...

Comment: *"pyinstaller при сборке добавляет вирусы"* - может, не стоит делать таких громких заявлений. Вы же сказали, что более авторитетные антивирусы не реагируют. Думаю, нужно разобраться детальнее.

Comment: Да, я добавил далее, что возможна антивири с вт так думают(что есть вирусы)

Comment: но я исправлю формулировку на более корректную

Comment: надеюсь, такая формулировка устраивает?

Comment: @Dospayne2, кстати, тоже 6 угроз в моем приложении на ВТ показывает

Answer (score 6):

pyinstaller - это [упаковщик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2). Для антивирусника будет выглядеть подозрительным любой исполняемый файл, пытающийся запустить то, что считал из себя.

Comment: прикол в том, что его вирусом обозначают малоизвестные антивирусы, более известные его определяют нормально

Comment: и он не просто выглядит подозрительно для некоторых из них, некоторые находят в нем конкретные трояны, но скорее всего, это ложное срабатывание

Comment: Потому что эти конкретные трояны так же упаковываются.

Comment: видимо, так и есть)