# Скрипт python распознается как вирус

Tags: python, pyinstaller, вирусы

Упаковал скрипт python в exe-файл с помощью pyInstaller, но он распознаётся многими антивирусами как вирус.

Как исправить ситуацию, что бы антивирусы так не реагировали на мою программу?

Comment: См. также: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1226514/1365, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/999504/1365

Comment: Avast небось? ))

Comment: и аваст и обычный 10 виндовский

Answer (score 0):

Запоковывай через `auto-py-to-exe` там есть интерфейс и очень удобен в использовании. УСТАНОВКА `pip install auto-py-to-exe`
После установки в терминале вводите `auto-py-to-exe` и появляется окно. Там есть русский язык. Эта программа также использует pyinstaller. И ваша проблема исчезнет.

Comment: auto-py-to-exe "под капотом" использует pyinstaller, так что суть от этого не изменится.

Comment: @insolor Антивирусы не будут агрится. У меня тоже была такая проблема. Я ее решил использованием auto-py-to-exe